# Searching 2d array for exact match of multiple strings

Tags: php

Not exactly sure if I'm approaching this the best way, probably not.

I have an array called $search with elements 'dog' and 'cat'. I want to search a 2d array called $array and store the first element (its a number) of each row if that row has elements of both 'dog' and 'cat'. I have this so far:

```
//create 2d array
$array = array(
    array(1, 'dog', 'cat','sup'),
    array(2, 'dog', 'fish', 'cow'),
    array(3, 'dog', 'cat'),
    array(4, 'monkey', 'rabbit', 'king', 'fish', 'duck')
);

//create user search array
$search = array('dog', 'cat');

//create get results array:
$results = array();

//get rows with matches of user search and push to results array:
$rows = count($array);
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    $cols = count($array[$row]);
    for($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ ) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++){
            if($search[$i] == $array[$row][$col]){
                //not sure what to do here...
                array_push($results, $array[$row][0]);
                //... 
            }
        }
    }
}

//check results
var_dump($results);
```

So, I would want only these rows to be pushed to the results array:

```
array(1, 'dog', 'cat','sup'),
array(3, 'dog', 'cat')
```

which would look like:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take an item from `$array` and check if it contais all values from `$search`.

Example:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($search as $sItem) {
        if (!in_array($sItem, $item))
            continue 2;
    }
    $results[] = $item[0];
}
```

Comment: good logic.. came to know the difference b/w continue and break

Comment: This approach doesn't work when the search array contains the same item several times.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it is not in the list of requirements (example data) (-;

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for` loops with arrays, use `foreach` that is designed for this task.

You can find `$array` items you want if you compare the size of the search array with the size of the intersection between `$array` items and the search array using `array_intersect` and `count`:

```
$array = [
    [1, 'dog', 'cat','sup'],
    [2, 'dog', 'fish', 'cow'],
    [3, 'dog', 'cat'],
    [4, 'monkey', 'rabbit', 'king', 'fish', 'duck']
];

$search = [ 'dog', 'cat'];
$size_search = count($search);
$store = [];

foreach ($array as $v) {
    if ( count(array_intersect($search, $v)) == $size_search )
        $store[] = $v[0];
}

print_r($store);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/OJ3IX)

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this using `in_array` function**

**Replace the for loop with this**

```
//get rows with matches of user search and push to results array:
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<sizeof($search);$j++){
  if (!in_array($search[$j], $array[$i]))
    continue 2;
  }
 $results[] = $array[$i][0];
}
//check results
var_dump($results);
```

**The result will be**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 3
```